# Какие юридические документы и конкретно в каких случаях нужны мобильному приложению? Какие юридические аспекты?

Tags: android, ios, публикация-приложений

Сразу говорю, что публиковать в сторах не собираюсь, размещаю apk на своём сайте. Везде, даже когда спрашиваешь про это chatGPT, то говорит, что для подробной информации нужна консультация с юристом, и конкретно не говорит. Если у кого-то есть опыт в этом деле, то буду весьма благодарен за помощь

Comment: Чем вас не устроили ответы месячной давности и то, что вам нейросеть советует? Вряд ли на сайте для программистов сидят юристы. Скорее всего вам надо именно к юристам обращаться за платной консультацией.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Но неужели никто с такими ситуациями не сталкивался? Все программисты что-то делают и выкладывают. Каждый день в сторах появляются новые приложения. Как эти люди понимают, какие именно документы им создавать? Не все же идут к юристам. Неужели никто не может поделиться своим опытом?

Comment: Всё что нужно написано в самих магазинах. Для регистрации нужнен паспорт для физ. лица. Для юр.лица - другие доки. В магазине каждом всё это написано. Там и попробуйте искать актуальную информацию. По моему опыту и опыту знакомых физ. лиц - ничего особенного нигде не нужно и никто никогда этим не парится. Вы первый человек за многие годы, которому это зачем-то понадобилось узнать тут.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб просто я хочу исключить все риски штрафования и т. п. А по документам я имею ввиду разные политики и условия использований.

Comment: Исключить риски штрафования невозможно. Даже если вы соблюдёте букву каждого закона каждой страны какой-то случайный судья может своим постановлением объявить что трактовать к-л закон надо иначе и вам выпишут миллиардный штраф и посадят пожизненно. С правилами магазинов приложений ещё хуже. Там вообще всё по большей части случайно. Берите абсолютно любой генератор политик и соглашений и используйте. И постоянно правьте политики по мере поступления проблем от них от регуляторов и магазинов. Юридическая беспроблемность не может быть целью, это процесс.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а можно ещё вопрос? Для мобильных приложений и сайтов достаточно лишь политики конфиденциальности и условий использования или ещё что-нибудь?

Comment: На данный момент это обязательный минимум. Далее нюансы. Например, если вы не свой контент используете - надо документы предоставлять с подтвержением разрешения на использование чужого контента, например. Или гос. лицензию на азартные игры, если у вас программа-казино. Или гос. документ о праве собирать мед. данные для отслеживания ковида, если вы такое приложение делаете. Etc

Comment: @ЮрийСПб а например для какой-то  соцсети этого достаточно?

Comment: Скорее всего да. Но если у вас будет там много юзеров вам надо будет штат модераторов создавать и общаться с аналогами ФСБ разных стран чтобы выдавать им личные данные неугодных юзеров и удалять запрещённую информацию по их запросу. Ещё, по идее, открывать офисы в разных странах и данные юзеров хранить на серверах в отдельных странах. Но, повторюсь, нет особого смысла думать заранее. Действуйте по обстоятельствам. Если чего-то не просят - не делайте

Comment: @ЮрийСПб если хотите, то можете добавить все что вы написали в ответ, а я отмечу его правильным и ещё я только недавно нашёл такой ресурс, добавьте в вопрос ссылку на него: https://cms.law/en/int/expert-guides/cms-expert-guide-to-data-protection-and-cyber-security-laws/united-kingdom